How to see Google Drive embedded video authorized to second Google Account?
I have two Google accounts logged in the same Chrome window

User 0: personal account
User 1: work account

There are some web pages in my company that have a Google Workspace (sheets, drive, docs, etc) document embedded. This document is not public, however, I have permission to view it with my work account.
The problem is that the main account in my browser is my personal account. Therefore, I don't see the document.
I am a web developer and I could edit the <iframe> code if necessary, or do whatever to force the work account to be considered.
What should I do as the maintainer of the website?

You should be able to switch between the Google accounts you are using to view Google Drive.  Have you tried that?
